# Na/NaN Argument when subsetting rows and columns with brackets

Tags: r, subset, nan, na

I'm currently trying to find my transactions from 2021 from a CSV file I downloaded from my bank's website, but when I try to subset the transactions from the dataset I get two warnings and one error.

```
chase.finances = chase[c('01/01/2021':'12/31/2021'), c('Amount', 'Posting.Date')]
```

Warning message in `[.data.frame`(chase, c("01/01/2021":"12/31/2021"), "Posting.Date"):
“NAs introduced by coercion”
Warning message in `[.data.frame`(chase, c("01/01/2021":"12/31/2021"), "Posting.Date"):
“NAs introduced by coercion”
Error in "01/01/2021":"12/31/2021": NA/NaN argument

Traceback:

1. chase[c("01/01/2021":"12/31/2021"), "Posting.Date"]
2. `[.data.frame`(chase, c("01/01/2021":"12/31/2021"), "Posting.Date")

edit: changed code

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[x %between% c('2021-01-01', '2021-12-31'), Posting.Date]
```

where `x` is your date column

Comment: I didn't work. This is part of the message I got.


    Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x): Object 'x' not found. Perhaps you intended 
    Debit/Credit, Posting.Date, Description, Amount, Type or 1 more
 
    Traceback:

Comment: `x` is the column you are subsetting by. Change this to your date column. It was not clear in your example what this column's name was.
The syntax in this solution says "bring back rows where column `x` is between '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31' (inclusive) then bring back column `Posting.Date`